# System.AggregateException in Web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, visual-studio-debugging

I have a ionic cordova app which points to a local(iis express) web api service.
The app is hosted on : http://localhost:8100/
Web api is hosted on : http://localhost:56776/

I get following error when my app hits the service:

no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

[image]

Inner Exception:
[image]

I have enabled the ports in windows firewall both in inbound and outbound rules. Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to connect your app to '127.0.0.1:60967' when you the URL for your API is http://localhost:56776/... What do you expect? Feed the correct resourceUri to your function.

Comment: Ohh yes, did not notice that.Thanks for pointing that out.Will work on it as soon as I am back after lunch.

Comment: Ohh My bad. Should have looked into the code in detailed way rather than relying upon other dev's word.T here was internal call to another web service which was not hosted in my machine. Thanks Brandon.

Comment: No problem. Glad this helped!